# arecord: main:828: audio open error: Device or resource busy RPi 4

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi4

Attempting to record on a RPI 4 running Pi OS (latest version)
Set audio to output - 3.5. jack
Set audio input to USB PnP Sound Device

Can get output, but when attempting to record get the following
 arecord ggg.wav or

arecord --device=plughw:2,0 ggg.wav

arecord: main:828: audio open error: Device or resource busy
pi@raspberrypi:~/Watson $  lsof | grep '/dev/snd'

lxpanel    749                              pi   15u      CHR     116,32      0t0       1796 /dev/snd/controlC1
lxpanel    749  781 gmain                   pi   15u      CHR     116,32      0t0       1796 /dev/snd/controlC1
lxpanel    749  783 gdbus                   pi   15u      CHR     116,32      0t0       1796 /dev/snd/controlC1
lxpanel    749  956 menu-cach               pi   15u      CHR     116,32      0t0       1796 /dev/snd/controlC1

pi@raspberrypi:~/Watson $ fuser /dev/snd/controlC1
/dev/snd/controlC1:    749

Any suggestions to remedy?